# Resize container on pressed (hide and show other widget)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

***Hi, is there any flutter widget that can do something like this?***

[image]

***When you click the arrow, the container resize and show other widget:***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [expandable package](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) might be helpful:

Example taken from the package page:

```
class ArticleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final Article article;
  
  ArticleWidget(this.article);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandablePanel(
      header: Text(article.title),
      collapsed: Text(article.body, softWrap: true, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
      expanded: Text(article.body, softWrap: true, ),
      tapHeaderToExpand: true,
      hasIcon: true,
    );
  }
}
```